# If I add new languages to my app, will it change over immediately on version update?

Tags: android, internationalization

I have an app that is currently being used across different countries. For example, Spain.

It's currently an English app, but I wanted to expand using [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html) setup. If I update the app to include these new languages, will those already using the app in Spain now see the new language? Or will they have to reinstall from the app store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have to update their app from the Play Store (unless they have it set to automatically update). Once they have the updated version, they should see the new language. Your app will be stopped temporarily while the update is being installed, and then it will be restarted. Resources (like strings) will be loaded again, and since you now have ones that are better match for the current configuration, it should use those.